# SAS - SQL Server - Set Identity_Insert ON

Tags: sql, sql-server, sas, proc-sql

I'm inserting a table into a SQL database and I have an `ID` column in my dataset. To insert it, I need to set identity_insert to on. How do I set `identity_insert` on using SAS in a `proc sql`?

```
proc sql;
    insert into db.app (id, name)
    select a.id a.name from work.test as a;
quit;
```

Answer (score 1):

Per [this SAS tech support note](http://support.sas.com/kb/2/627.html), you do it as follows:

```
libname x odbc dsn=mssqlserver user=xxx password=yyy
dbconinit='set IDENTITY_INSERT foo ON'
dbconterm='set IDENTITY_INSERT foo OFF';

proc append base=x.foo data=work.foo;
run;
```

This assumes you need to actually set the `id` variable.  You should be able to just leave the `id` variable off of the insert statement if you want it autoincremented.

Comment: I saw that when I looked up the problem but I don't understand it. What are dbconinit and foo placeholders for?

Comment: `foo` is your dataset.   `dbconinit` is not a placeholder, it's a setting on the libname statement - notice the lack of semicolon. It's instructions for telling SQL Server what to do when the connection initializes (and then `dbconterm` is instructions on termination).